# How to call an API that is a more complex array, in JavaScript using fetch (and display it)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch-api

I am trying to learn more about APIs and calling them correctly. I have been using the fetch method. My code, which includes the API I'm referencing:

```js
  fetch('https://datausa.io/api/data?drilldowns=Nation&measures=Population')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                appendData(data);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
            });
        function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data[0].Population;
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
           // }
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JSON Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myData"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to call upon "Population" for 2019 and display it. This is easy with a basic API with only one set of curly brackets and no arrays - but for this one I think I'm getting my arrays and objects mixed up and am not coding it in correctly, any suggestions?

Comment: The API response is `{ data: [...], ... }` which means you'll need `data.data[0]`. You can also do `appendData(data.data);` instead.

Comment: Are you by chance wanting to use a [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to iterate over the array entries, and add those entries to the DOM, one-at-a-time?

Comment: Thank you @Chris G and others below! That worked. Looks like I have to dive deeper into this anyway to get the hang of it.

Comment: What I would suggest in the future is to stick to calling the response `response` and logging stuff. For instance `console.log(response);` would have logged an object with a "data" key, so next you can try `console.log(response.data);`, this time getting an array. And so on. (It's also pretty annoying that axios, a popular library which became basically useless thanks to fetch, actually uses `.data` to get to the actual API reply, so in your case you'd have had to use `data.data.data[0]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API returns an object with `"data"` property so you can use `"data"` property to display populations like this.

```js
fetch('https://datausa.io/api/data?drilldowns=Nation&measures=Population')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    const responseData = data.data;
    appendData(responseData);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('error: ' + err);
  });

function appendData(data) {
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById('myData');
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data[0].Population;
  mainContainer.appendChild(div);
  
}
```

Comment: There's no need to post an answer here; this is a typo-type question that doesn't have to be preserved for future readers.